# How to save locally user data in AS3, and then read it/export it?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, save, flash-builder

Hey there, i was wondering what the AS3 experts would do to perform this task: save user data (registry form) locally, and then be able to read it or export it into something client can read.

Thanks in advance, i am quite new to the AS3 approach to this things, thing to notice is this project is pure AS3, and deployed in Adobe AIR, so no server programming.

Comment: sounds like two different tasks...

For saving user data I would go with shared objects before saving locally, but saving a file works too, however there is a bit more work required in reading/writing data. However if you need to read and write the data externally anyway, then that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to AIR features, you can save large amounts of data in a file:

```
var storage:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("data.xml");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(storage, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeSomething //there are various .writeXXX functions
stream.close();
```

I would save xml file (just to avoid inventing custom parser), then read it back.

Answer (score 3):

you can save data in SharedObject to make it readable from flash. 
if you need to export it to a user defined location you can use FileReference.save() method, but to read it back the user must enter the path to file manually

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your data, you could use a [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to save your data locally.

As for something the client can read , can you be more specific?